# How do I make the vertical scrollbar bigger and/or more to the left in chromium-browser in kiosk mode on a Raspberry Pi 4?

Tags: html, css, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3, chromium

I have an MHS 3.5inch display (480x320) LCD display connected to a Raspberry Pi 3 Model B+. I'm running chromium-browser using `chromium-browser --kiosk --incognito`.

But when I have HTML page that causes a vertical scrollbar to appear, most of the scrollbar is off the right edge of the screen. (I can't even see the arrows.)

---

[image: test scrolled to top]

---

[image: test scrolled down just a bit]

---

[image: test scrolled most of the way down]

---

How do I configure Chromium or the display (or my HTML/CSS) so the scrollbar is more to the left and/or bigger?

---

**Update:** I tried [Sean Grant](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6073415/sean-grant)'s suggestion:

```
<style type="text/css">
    ::-webkit-scrollbar {
      width: 20px;
    }
</style>
```

...but the scrollbar didn't look any different.

Answer (score 3):

You can target the scrollbar in CSS. It doesn't work in every browser (see [caniuse](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-scrollbar)), but Chromium should be able to support it. You would make a rule like such:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 20px;
}
```

Comment: Can I only change the width? (Can I move it with a border or margin?)

Comment: Check out [this css-tricks.com article](https://css-tricks.com/the-current-state-of-styling-scrollbars/). You can do a lot with the size and color, but not so much with the positioning.